# can anyone tell what this command will do

Tags: shell, sed, autoconf

```
%build
# Build all apps
{
for app in * ; do
    pushd $app
    sed -i '/XAW_/ s/)/, xaw7)/; /XAW_/ s/XAW_CHECK_XPRINT_SUPPORT/PKG_CHECK_MODULES/' configure.ac
    autoreconf -v --install
    %configure --disable-xprint
    make
    popd
done
}
```

can anyone tell me  what operations will sed command do on  configure.ac and autoreconf

Comment: Primarily, this command causes the software gods to roll over in their graves.  Automatically built software should be built from tarballs, not from autoconf meta-files!  (Nearly) any automated build that invokes the autotools is fundamentally broken.  An automated build that edits the meta files before invoking the autotools is an abomination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed-command will look for lines matching `XAW_` and - when found - replace `)` with `, xaw7)`, and `XAW_CHECK_XPRINT_SUPPORT` with `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.

**[EDIT]** `autoreconf` will look for any missing "auxiliary files" and install them. [See the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html) for details.